# Cross Domain Request to SAP authentication service

Tags: authentication, active-directory

I've to authenticate my webapp using a third party `SAP authentication service`. On hitting the service, it redirects the request to a `Active Directory` server, which authenticates the user and redirects back to the third party server. This third party server doesn't redirect back to me. Is there a way in which I can get the session details?

I thought of using an IFrame, but then I won't be able to access session details set to IFrame by the third party server.

Is there any other way in which I can solve this and get session details?